# CMake python linking issues

Tags: python, c, cmake

I started working with CMake yesterday, so still very, very, novice. I am trying to embed some python in c, more precisely I want to call a python script from my c program. I have been going off a few resources online and I have gotten the best results following this post, [CMake not linking Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817266/cmake-not-linking-python).

As for embedding my python code, my implementation is pretty much a 1:1 of [this python documentation example, section 5.3](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html).

In my **CMakeLists.txt** I have

```
   find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
   include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   add_library(TARS SHARED ${SOURCES})
   target_link_libraries(TARS ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

which builds but gives me a resulting **libTARS.so**. My problem is such that I need this to be an executable and I am not sure how to do just that. I have played around with something similar to

```
   find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
   include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   add_library(TARS SHARED ${SOURCES})
   target_link_libraries(TARS ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
   add_executable(TARSEXEC ${SOURCES})
   target_link_libraries(TARSEXEC TARS)
```

which gives me a few errors for undefined references to some python wrapper functions. Like I said, super new to CMake so I might be making some very obvious and silly mistakes. Any help or nudges in the right direction would be appreciated.

Cheers

Update:

I have gone for the following CMake config

```
   find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
   include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   add_executable(TARS ${SOURCES})
   target_link_libraries(TARS ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

And it is giving me the following errors

> /home/alxhoff/git/siemens/siemens-personal/TARS/src/main.c:101:
>   undefined reference to `PyString_FromString'
>
> /home/alxhoff/git/siemens/siemens-personal/TARS/src/main.c:139:
>   undefined reference to `PyInt_AsLong'
>
> /home/alxhoff/git/siemens/siemens-personal/TARS/src/main.c:160:
>   undefined reference to `Py_Finalizer'

After some grepping I have found that the default 3.5 version of python lacks these functions whilst 2.7 contains them. I now just need to force CMake to use 2.7.

Solved using the following

```
set(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE "/usr/bin/python2.7")
set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/include/python2.7")
set(PYTHON_LIBRARIES "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so")
```

Comment: If you need an executable, replace ` add_library(TARS SHARED ${SOURCES})` with ` add_executable(TARS ${SOURCES})`, obviously. If that gives you undefined references, post the error message.

Comment: I believe now it is a python version error @arrowd. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following to **CMakeLists.txt**

```
   find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)

   set(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE "/usr/bin/python2.7")
   set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/include/python2.7")
   set(PYTHON_LIBRARIES "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so")

   include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   add_executable(TARS ${SOURCES})
   target_link_libraries(TARS ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

thus forcing the use of python 2.7

Comment: This defeats the purpose of `find_package`. The proper way is to `set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 2.7)` before calling `find_package`. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindPythonLibs.html

Comment: That does seem like a cleaner soloution @arrowd although I am still getting the errors if I use it instead :\ Although only one now not the three, `PyString_FromString' is still undefined

Comment: How about `--ldflags`?