# CMakeLists with g++ options

Tags: g++, cmakelists-options

In my project, there is a cpp file with Python.h. Therefore, I tried to compile this file with following command:

**g++ {fileName}.cpp -I/usr/include/python3.6m -lpython3.6m**

However, I am wondering how can I make CMakeLists for adding options like "**-I/usr/include/python3.6m**" and "**-lpython3.6m**".

This is my very simple CMakeLists.txt

```cpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

add_executable (program test.cpp)
target_include_directories(program PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/python3.6m)
target_compile_options(program PUBLIC "-lpython3.6m")

message(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/python3.6m)
```

---

Thanks to Fridrich, I modified the CMakeLists.txt file, if you make a cpp file with python.h and try to compile the files with cmake, use 'target_link_libraries' as following:

```cpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
    
add_executable(program test.cpp)
target_include_directories(program PUBLIC /usr/include/python3.6m) 
# Third option means the location of the directory of header files.
target_link_libraries(program PUBLIC "-lpython3.6m")
   
message(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/python3.6m)
```

Comment: Does this help: [CMake not linking python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817266/cmake-not-linking-python)?

Comment: It is helpful for improving my CMakeLists.txt, but still I do not know how can add -lpython3.6m option...

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) What is it you want to accomplish? You don't want to add random g++ options - you want to link to python in a CMake project. Look into [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html)

Comment: I'm so sorry for inconvenience. My goal is to make CMakeLists.txt file with -l option, and thanks to your link library page, I can generate perfect CMakelists.txt. I'll write a question with a more accurate point next time. Thank you.

Comment: Don't be sorry, SO is for asking questions. If you found a solution, please post an answer below so others can benefit from your research. Thank you.